# Using beautifulsoup to scrape <h2> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website data using beautiful soup. I want the the anchor value (My name is nick) of the following. But i searched a lot in the google but can't find any perfect solution to solve my query.

```
news_panel = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'menuNewsPanel_MenuNews1'})
for news in news_panel:
    temp = news.find('h2')        
    print temp
```

output :

```
<h2 class="menuNewsHl2_MenuNews1"><a href="index.php?ref=MjBfMDFfMDhfMTRfMV84XzFfOTk2NDA=">My name is nick</a></h2>
```

But i want output like this :  `My name is nick`

Answer (score 5):

Just grab the `text` attribute:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<h2 class="menuNewsHl2_MenuNews1"><a href="index.php?ref=MjBfMDFfMDhfMTRfMV84XzFfOTk2NDA=">My name is nick</a></h2>''')
>>> soup.text
u'My name is nick'
```

Comment: I want it in the function. I have tried temp.text . But it is showing error.

Comment: temp3 = temp.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: and the code is :

 for news in news_panel:
        temp = news.find('h2')
        temp3 = temp.text

Comment: Ah, that means not all `news.find('h2')` elements has a text. Do you want to bypass the ones without a text?

Comment: Check first if the tag has a text : `if temp3.text is not None:`

Comment: @aIKid You are wrong - if the element doesn't have any text inside, BS will just return an empty string. Try it yourself: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; soup = BeautifulSoup('<html></html>'); print soup.html.text`

Comment: @SteinarLima My bad. What i mean was, that means not all `news_panel` elements has an `<h2>` tag inside.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is probably occurring because you don't have that specific tag in your input string.

Check if `temp` is not None

```
news_panel = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'menuNewsPanel_MenuNews1'})
for news in news_panel:
    temp = news.find('h2')
    if temp:
        print temp.text
```

or put your print statement in a `try ... except` block

```
news_panel = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'menuNewsPanel_MenuNews1'})
for news in news_panel:
    try:
        print news.find('h2').text
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
all_string=soup.find_all("h2")[0].get_text()
```

Comment: Context please?